# Asp.Net Identity Unauthorized redirect Not Working with Custom Routes

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership, url-routing, asp.net-identity

Forms Authentication used to redirect to the login page when a folder was configured to restrict authentication to a user. As configured in the web.config, in the folder.

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>      
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Which would redirect you to the login page with the returnurl of where you wanted to go in the first place. The authorization works ( Identity 2.0 Beta1 prerelease ) but there is no redirect to the login page and I'm not able to make this happen though Ive gone through quite a bit on Identity. Now, after implementing identity which does everything else quiet well, when I try to access a page that requires me to be logged in I see a YSOD saying.

> An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources.

I've used the default template from vs2013 and as soon as I put in the custom route it stopped working and I've tried soo many things, I just can't get it to work..

I figured out that when I enabled FriendlyUrls or the full path of the resource and used the url route to a resource that was restricted to Logged in users it worked.

**For example** I have a page located at /Account/nightlife/stream.aspx which has that web.config in the folder Account

So when I use the full path **it works** and sends me to the login page with

```
http://mylocaliis/login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2Fnightlife%2Fstream.aspx (without the .aspx in the case of friendly urls)
```

When I was using Forms Authentication a few weeks ago this problem didnt exist with the custom route you can see for the login page

> (which is -  routes.MapPageRoute( routeName:"login", routeUrl: "login", physicalFile: "~/Account/Login.aspx" ); )

But with Identity and the custom route enabled the redirect dosent happen and I see the YSOD

**So for example** if i tried to access the resource (when I am not logged in) with its custom route url

```
localhost/stream (defined by the custom route -  routes.MapPageRoute( "nightlife_stream", "stream", "~/Account/nightlife/stream.aspx" ); )
```

I see the YSOD.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I just ran into this today as well and fixed it. Basically, if you create a route and the user is not logged in but needs to be, you get the YSOD (yellow screen of death) even though your MapPageRoute specifies true for the "checkPhysicalUrlAccess" parameter.

To resolve this, I added a check in the Application_AuthenticationRequest method of Global.asax. So, my code is something like this...

Inside Application_Start in Global.asax I registered my route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("EditAPage", "editpage/{pageToken}", "Admin/editpage.aspx", true);
```

Then I added this to Global.asax:

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
    string url = Request.Url.ToString();

    if (url.Contains("/editpage") && user == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2Feditpage");
    }
}
```

I will need to evolve this a bit more as I also have additional pages where a user needs to be authenticated and authorized and it would be ideal not to have to create an individual check for each route that I end up adding... but, for now, this is redirecting my user's to login. I will also need to add handling to append the {pageToken} to the ReturnUrl - if the token is provided that is.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a legacy project and had to fix this issue.

1. Unauthorized access normally has Http Code of 401
2. The app throws a YSOD meaning the error may have to go through Application_Error in Global.asax and the error may not be necessarily a HttpException
3. If it is an error of HttpCode 401, then use *HttpContext.Current.ClearError()* method to clear the current error and prevent YSOD.

Solution:

```
  void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        try
        {
            HttpException httpException = (HttpException)ex;
            int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            if (httpCode == 401)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
                string url = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
                Response.Redirect($"~/LogIn/?ReturnUrl={url}");
            }
            else
            {
                //Log Your Error
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            //Log Your Error
        }

    }
```